# Finding positive and negative edges using a sobel filter

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a binary barcode image, I want to apply a sobel filter that I created so that I can detect the positive/negative vertical edges of the barcode lines which I can then use to determine the start/end of each barcode line. 
The idea of implementing my own sobel filter is so that I can preserve the polarity(for start/end of each barcode line) and then plot different color lines over the positive/negative values marking the beginning and end of each bar in the barcode.

My problem is that I am not getting every line from my original barcode when I apply my filter in my output image. Can anyone see the problem in my code?

```
Image =imread('barcode.jpg')
I = im2double(Image);
G  = rgb2gray(I);
avgI=mean(mean(G))
Threshold = avgI;
T=(G<Threshold);


figure()
New = T.*G
imshow(New);
G = [1 0 -1
     2 0 -2 
     1 0 -1];

Output = I;
for n = 1:1000
Output = conv2(New,G); % 2D Convolution Function
end

subplot(1,2,1), imshow (New);
subplot(1,2,2), imshow (Output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the convolution operation directly on the thresholded image. Also make sure to convert it to `double` since it will be of class `logical`. Lastly I dont know why you were performing the convolution 1000 times but overall I think you put in a good effort and were relatively close to a solution.

Code:

```
Image =imread('barcode.jpg');
I = im2double(Image);
G  = rgb2gray(I);
avgI=mean(mean(G));
Threshold = avgI;
T=(G<Threshold);


figure
G = [1 0 -1
     2 0 -2 
     1 0 -1];

Output = conv2(double(T),G); % 2D Convolution Function

subplot(1,2,1), imshow (T,[]);
subplot(1,2,2), imshow (Output,[]);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much, I was supposed to remove that for loop before posting originally.